# how to get nested selectors in siblings

Tags: javascript

I need to find the siblings of one element. The object I desire to get is nested input. The code belove navigates to td[2] where I need to do some comparison. Afterwords when the comparison is made I need to get to td[4] which contains input. I did try to use nextsibling function but something goes wrong :( Here is the image of html: [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLEHI.jpg)

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("table.table.table-condensed.table-top-spacing tr td:nth-child(2)");
    inputs.forEach((input)=>{
        var final_input = input.find("input[name='quantity']");
        final_input.click;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to docs Using `Node.nextSibling` `Node.firstChild` or `Node.previousSibling` may refer to a whitespace text node rather than the actual element.

You can track the element's siblings with the example introduced in the MDN documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).

```
var el = input;
i = 1;

while (el) {
  if(el.nodeName ==="TARGET_ELEMENT")
      break;
  console.log(i, '. ', el.nodeName);
  el = el.previousSibling;
  i++;
}
```

Comment: It doesn;t work as this input is not nested in loop element (input). It is located in the next sibling

Comment: I remember recently I was dealing with exact same problem, I just create a wrapper that contains both of my elements and actually change my selector to that so both of the elements be present in the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root cause of your problem is that `find` is not a method that exists on HTML elements. You might be mistaking it for JQuery.

Instead, you want to use `parentElement.querySelector`:

```js
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('table tr td:nth-child(2)');
cells.forEach(cell => {
  if (cell.textContent === '1') {
    const input = cell.parentElement.querySelector('input[name="quantity"]');
    input.value = 'matched';
  }
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>input</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantity" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>input</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantity" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>input</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantity" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```